# Regex to remove div tags but not their content

Tags: php, html, regex

Let's say this is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><div style="width: 10em;">Hello</div><div class="ble"></div></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, all div opening and closing tags were removed but not their content!

This is what I have so far:

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/<div.*>/';
$patterns[1] = '/</div>/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = '';
$replacements[1] = '';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $html);
```

Comment: Thou shalt not use regex for parsing or modifying XML.

Comment: @Scytale Unfortunately I have no choice in this situation. I try to use PHP DOM in all other cases though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/regex: How to get the string value of HTML tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828870/php-regex-how-to-get-the-string-value-of-html-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `'/<div.*>/'` with `'/<div.*?>/'` This will remove greedy behavior of the `*` and match the first `>` encountered.

Also, you need to escape the backslash in your pattern for matching the closing tag - use:

```
'/<\/div>/';
```

Comment: I get this error: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'd' in...

Comment: @Richard, escape the backslash in `'/</div>/'`: `'/<\/div>/'`, or use a different delimiter: `'#</div>#'`

Comment: @richard m afraid I may not be able to help you in that as I am not a php guy.

Comment: @Gopi just add the backshlash as bart K. suggested and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with replacing both `<div[^>]*>` and `</div[^>]*>`with nothing. Though I know little about the specific PHP regex engine, the following `sed` worked fine:

```
pax> cat qq.in
<ul>
    <li><div style="width: 10em;">Hello</div><div class="ble"></div></li>
</ul>

pax> cat qq.in | sed -e 's/<div[^>]*>//g' -e 's/<\/div>//g'
<ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

In fact, you should be able to combine that into one regex `</?div[^>]*>`:

```
pax> cat qq.in | sed -r -e 's_</?div[^>]*>__g'
<ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
</ul>
```