# PHP How to split a string with 2 delimiters with php starting by the right

Tags: php, string, substring, delimiter

I need delimiter a string (it's html) and i need extract a substring, but i only have a function to delimiter by the left:

```
function ddd($str, $sLeft, $sRight)
{
$pleft = strpos($str, $sLeft, 0);
$pright = strpos($str, $sRight, $pleft + strlen($sLeft));
return (substr($str, $pleft + strlen($sLeft), ($pright - ($pleft + strlen($sLeft)))));
}
```

but i need start on the right ($sRight) and end at $sLeft.
Thanks!

Comment: And your question is? How to "delimiter" by the right?

Comment: Try giving an example of input and desired output

Comment: I have:
[some html]<div><span class="some style bla bla assd dfsdf">ImportantText</span></[some html]
i would extract the ImportantText, but my function split by the left, and i use function($string,">","</span>") but starting the split by the right

Comment: whoa...such a vague question...the answer could just as well be "yorkshire pudding"

Comment: i only need in my function start by the right side

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to search the string by the left side, and also by the right side. If that is the case you can use this [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php#92158):

**PHP**

```
<?php

// Function from php.net, see the link above.
// Starts searching the value from the right side
// of the string, returning the pos
function backwardStrpos($haystack, $needle, $offset = 0){
    $length = strlen($haystack);
    $offset = ($offset > 0)?($length - $offset):abs($offset);
    $pos = strpos(strrev($haystack), strrev($needle), $offset);
    return ($pos === false) ? (false) : ($length - $pos - strlen($needle));
}

$string = 'My string is this, and it is a good dialog';
echo backwardStrpos($string, "i"); // outputs 37
echo strpos($string, "i", 0);      // outputs 6

?>
```

**ILLUSTRATED VERSION OF THE OUTPUT:**

[image]

---

## EDITED

You've just placed a comment related to what you are trying to do.

**For that you can use [PHP strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):**

```
<?php

$str = '<div><span class="some style bla bla assd dfsdf">ImportantText</span>';

echo strip_tags($str); //outputs: ImportantText

?>
```

---

## EDITED

To extract text between HTML tags:

```
<?php

function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

$str = '<div><span class="some style bla bla assd dfsdf">ImportantText</span>';
$txt = getTextBetweenTags($str, "span");
echo $txt; // outputs: ImportantText

?>
```

This came from a fellow stackoverflow! [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/828870/352449)

Comment: I have more text but only one in <span> and i only need this

Comment: See my last edit at the end of my answer! With that small function you can collect the text between your span, or any other HTML tag.