# Find all <pre> tags in PHP (with attributes)

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, tags

I was following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828870/php-regex-how-to-get-the-string-value-of-html-tag) on how to retrieve all tags in PHP.

Specifically (under wordpress), I'd like to *find all* `<pre>` *tags*, with all the available information (attributes and text). However, it seems that I'm not that skilled in [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match), so I'm turning to you.

My text **does** contain various `<pre>` tags, some with attributes, some with just text. My function is this:

```
function getPreTags($string) {
    $pattern = "/<pre\s?(.*)>(.*)<\/pre>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

I've reduced to a test with just **one** `<pre>` tag, but I get `count(getPreTags(myHTMLbody)) = 0`, and I don't know why. This is the test string:

```
<pre class="wp-code-highlight prettyprint prettyprinted" style=""><span class="com">Whatever &lt;</span> I've written &gt;&gt; here <span class="something">should be taken care of</span></pre>
```

Any hint?

Cheers!

Comment: Use none greedy matchers `.*?` to fetch all `<pre ...>` so you end up with `/<pre\s?(.*?)>(.*?)<\/pre>/`

Comment: I don't understand. I've tried `"/<pre\s?.*?>(.*)<\/pre>/"` but it still gives me `count(matches[0]) = 0`.

Comment: Use **exactly** my pattern above.

Comment: Ok, but I still get count 0 with `echo count(getPreTags($obj));`, where the function is my function with the pattern `/<pre\s?(.*?)>(.*?)<\/pre>/`...

Comment: I get `1` by `count()` your functions return value with the exact same HTML string you posted above. Are there any linebreaks you cleared out from your original HTML string before you posted it here?

Comment: Yes. As I said, I'm using wordpress, so some characters are encoded by WP (_e.g._, <, >). I also see that after `<pre>` WP (or TinyMCE?) removes the first newline which I usually add after the tag.

Comment: Okay then please post your exact HTML output you're dealing with. So I can provide you a working regex.

Comment: See for instance (http://pastebin.com/GA2XS3rB) --- I was trying the other solutions, but at the end you see a very basic example of a C++ code in a `<pre>` tag, with a custom class.

Comment: Okay than you have to add the multiline matcher at the end of the pattern, so you get: `/<pre\s?(.*?)>(.*?)<\/pre>/ms`

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER it works now, and I can even get the index of all matches, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As ever, parsing HTML with regex is never going to cut it. There are so many things to take into account (tag-soup, spacing: `<pre>`==`<   pre >`==`<\n\t\sPrE\n\n>`...), any regex will fail you at some point. That's why there are such things as parsers, readily available.

That said: I have no idea why the other answers go through the trouble of using an instance of `DOMXPath`, when you need *all* `pre` tags, including those without attributes.
I'd go for something more simple, like:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);
$preTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('pre');
foreach($preTags as $pre)
{
    echo $pre->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
    if ($pre->hasAttributes())
    {//if there are attributes
        foreach($pre->attributes as $attribute)
        {
            //do something with attribute
            echo 'Attribute: ', $attribute->name, ' = ', $attribute->value, PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

What methods and properties are available to you can be found easily on these pages:

- Attributes: [`DOMAttr` class docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domattr.php)
- Nodes: [`DOMNode` class docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)
- Document: [`DOMDocument` class docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domcomment.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should better use DOM parser for parsing out HTML. Consider this code:

```
$html = <<< EOF
<a href="http://example.com/foo.htm" class="curPage">Click link1</a> morestuff
<pre>A    B    C</pre>
<a href="http://notexample.com/foo/bar">notexample.com</a> morestuff
<pre id="pre1">X    Y    Z</pre>
<a href="http://example.com/foo.htm">Click link1</a>
<pre id="pre2">1    2    3</pre>
EOF;

// create a new DOM object
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// select all pre tags with attributes
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//pre[@*]");

// iterate through selected nodes and print them
for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodelist->item($i);
    var_dump($node->nodeValue);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string(11) "X    Y    Z"
string(11) "1    2    3"
```

Comment: Although this is a very nice solutions, I don't have the whole DOM, just the content of a wordpress item :(

Comment: @senseiwa: As shown in above example you **don't need full page (DOM)** to make it work.

Comment: Mmmh, then I have some problems in my code: it stops evaluating. Here (http://pastebin.com/a5peRVp6) you can find my code: `$obj` contains the wordpress item. The function will only print "START", and then it stops.

Comment: Can you show content of `$obj` by calling `var_dump($obj);` at the start of this function.

Comment: @senseiwa: I don't see your HTML content. Can you paste it here by editing your question OR on pastebin?

Comment: Ok, I've uploaded in (http://pastebin.com/GA2XS3rB) the functions. I've changed the content of `<pre>` so that I get as many non-HTML-friendly characters (a simple C++ code from the web). Note that I removed the loop, since I was worried I've pasted incorrectly, now I just return the resulting nodes.

Comment: I am sorry, but the execution still hangs in my environment. Here (http://pastebin.com/jLv5sFeT) you can find the code, with uberuseless echos: it stops after printing "1".

Comment: Can you make a demo of your code on `ideone.com` as I showed to you above. It will be much easier to fix then.

Comment: Ok, I've made this (http://ideone.com/PPfxSI). Here it works, however, on wordpress it doesn't. Sincerely, I'm at loss here. It's a simple copy/paste, and I dont't really understand what's going on here.

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly here. Can you try to var_dump your `$obj` in production env?

Comment: Of course, here (http://pastebin.com/rStKND1H) is the dump of the HTML output when **not** using the Xpath function. Note that the `$obj` is everything **inside** the `<div>`, I've left that only for clarification.

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Only problem I can see in your code is that you're returning `$nodelist`. I believe you should be returning an array of `$nodelist->nodeValue`

Comment: Even using `$res = array();` and in the loop, instead of `var_dump` using `array_push($res, $node->nodeValue);`, the execution flow stops. I have no clue.

Comment: What do you mean by `execution flow stops`? Does it just hang?

Comment: Yes, as I said previously, in production the code (http://pastebin.com/BeTxXaQD) hangs after `echo 2;` (in this new code): it seems it I am unable to use `$doc = new DOMDocument();`...

Comment: Unless I see problem being reproduced it is quite difficult to investigate & fix.

Comment: I do agree. I should follow the infamous "regexp" path, then. I don't see problems in the code, I copied it! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If the data is XML-conform, you could maybe use a XPATH expression.

Just a very quick one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>1</pre>
    <pre>2</pre>
    <pre>3</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then a PHP like this:

```
<?php
        $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
        $xmldoc->load('test.xml');

        $xpathvar = new Domxpath($xmldoc);

echo $xpathvar->evaluate('count(*//pre)');
?>
```

This should also work with html/xml snippets.

Comment: Unfortunately, wordpress doesn't allow me to hook to every aspect (I'm not that skilled), but I can retrieve the string of an item, which isn't a real DOM…