# PHP Regexp replace: get number of instances

Tags: php, regex

is there a way to replace a pattern using `preg_replace`, and putting in the replacement the *index of occurrence*?

For instance, in a string like

```
<p class='first'>hello world</p>
<p class='second'>this is a string</p>
```

I would like to use

```
preg_replace("/<p\s?(.*?)>(.*?)<\/pp>/ms", "<pre \\1 id='myid\\?'>\\2</pre>", $obj);
```

where `\\?` would be transformed to 0, and 1, so that the output would be

```
<pre class='first' id='myid0'>hello world</pre>
<pre class='second' id='myid1'>this is a string</pre>
```

Cheers & Thanks!

Comment: Hint use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/preg-replace-callback) if you must go this route.

```
$html = <<<DATA
<p class='first'>hello world</p>
<p class='second'>this is a string</p>
<p class='third'>this is another string</p>
DATA;

$html = preg_replace_callback('~<p\s*([^>]*)>([^>]*)</p>~', 
      function($m) { 
         static $id = 0;                                
         return "<pre $m[1] id='myid" . $id++ . "'>$m[2]</pre>"; 
      }, $html);
  
echo $html;
```

Output

```
<pre class='first' id='myid0'>hello world</pre>
<pre class='second' id='myid1'>this is a string</pre>
<pre class='third' id='myid2'>this is another string</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **dump the regex route** and use safer and proper way of doing this i.e. DOM parser. Consider this code:

```
$html = <<< EOF
<p class='first'>hello world</p>
<p class='second'>this is a string</p>
EOF;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// find all the <p> nodes
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//p");
// loop through <p> notes
for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodelist->item($i);
    // set id attribute
    $node->setAttribute('id', 'myid'.$i);
}
// save your modified HTML into a string
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
echo $html;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<html><body>
<p class="first" id="myid0">hello world</p>
<p class="second" id="myid1">this is a string</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I know you're totally right, but my production environment, as discussed in a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763868/find-all-pre-tags-in-php-with-attributes), hangs on DOM modifications. I still don't know why :(

Comment: That's very strange, never heard of anything like that PHP installation.