# How to parse html tags multiple times? PHP

Tags: php, html

String I'm trying to parse.

`<b>Genre:</b> <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Action/?snr=1_5_9__408">Action</a>, <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Adventure/?snr=1_5_9__408">Adventure</a>, <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Casual/?snr=1_5_9__408">Casual</a>, <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Early%20Access/?snr=1_5_9__408">Early Access</a>, <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Indie/?snr=1_5_9__408">Indie</a>, <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/genre/RPG/?snr=1_5_9__408">RPG</a><br>`

What I'm trying to achieve (without all the other tags etc):

`Action
Adventure
Casual
Early Access
Indie
RPG`

Here's what I've tried

```
        function getTagInfo($content,$start,$end){
            $r = explode($start, $content);
            if (isset($r[1])){
                $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
                return $r[0];
            }
            return '0';
        }


 getTagInfo($html, '/?snr=1_5_9__408">', '</a>');
```

and that only gives me one genre, I can't think of an algorithm to be able to parse the rest also, so how would I be able to parse the other lines?

Comment: You may want to look into an HTML parser for PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: you can parse the DOM using http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp's here:

```
<a.*?>(.*?)</a>
```

This RegExp will return all `<a></a>` contetns.

Try this php code:

```
preg_match(/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/, $htmlString, $matches);

foreach($matches as $match) {
    echo $match . " <br /> "; 
}
```

This will output:

```
Action 
Adventure 
Casual 
Early 
Access 
Indie 
RPG
```

---

Comment: Updated code. `/` symbol have to be escaped by `\\` .

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code from another stackoverflow thread.

[PHP/regex: How to get the string value of HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828870/php-regex-how-to-get-the-string-value-of-html-tag)

```
 <?php
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

$str = '<textformat leading="2"><p align="left"><font size="10">get me</font></p></textformat>';
$txt = getTextBetweenTags($str, "font");
echo $txt;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match_all`:

```
$regex = '/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/is';
preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will then be an array of the contents between the anchor tags and you could iterate over it like this:

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $match)
{
  echo $match .'<br>';
}
```

It would probably be better to use an actual [HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php), as HTML is not regualr syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this ([DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/93T9mS)):

```
function getTagInfo($html)
{
    if( preg_match_all('/<a href=\"(.*?)\">/i', $html, $matches)) {
        $result = array();
        foreach($matches[1] as $href) {
            $array = explode('/', $href);
            $arr = $array[count($array) - 2];
            $result[] = urldecode($arr);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}

// Get an array
print_r(getTagInfo($html));
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Action 
    [1] => Adventure 
    [2] => Casual 
    [3] => Early Access 
    [4] => Indie 
    [5] => RPG 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this with REGEX also, but since there are already 4 posts with REGEX answers, I'll throw another idea out there.  This may be overly simple, but you can use `strip_tags` to remove any HTML tags.

```
$string = '<b>Genre:</b> <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Action/?snr=1_5_9__408">Action</a>, <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Adventure/?snr=1_5_9__408">Adventure</a>, <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Casual/?snr=1_5_9__408">Casual</a>, <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Early%20Access/?snr=1_5_9__408">Early Access</a>, <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Indie/?snr=1_5_9__408">Indie</a>, <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/genre/RPG/?snr=1_5_9__408">RPG</a><br>';

print strip_tags($string);
```

This will return the following:

```
Genre: Action, Adventure, Casual, Early Access, Indie, RPG
```

Anyway, it's probably not how I'd go about doing it, but it's a one-liner that is really easy to implement.

I reckon, you can also turn it into the array you're looking for by combining the preceeding with some REGEX like this:

```
$string_array = preg_split('/,\s*/', preg_replace('/Genre:\s+/i', '', strip_tags($string)));

print_r($string_array);
```

That will give you the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Action
    [1] => Adventure
    [2] => Casual
    [3] => Early Access
    [4] => Indie
    [5] => RPG
)
```

Ha, sorry ... ended up throwing REGEX into the answer anyway.  But it's still a one-liner.  :)