# Replace text with html tags in it from HTML file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I created a simple jquery plugin for a client of mine, that takes his HTML file, and allows him to click on an area, and replace its HTML content.

For example, clicking on a div, will prompt him a form to enter the new text. when clicking "ok" it will send ajax request with the HTML code of the div he clicked on.

In PHP, i'm going over all of the tags that were sent from Ajax, and I want to replace them with a different text, then saving the newly created HTML file.

Lets say I got:

```
<h1>Welcome to my Website!</h1>
```

I want to change it to whatever he specified before,

so

```
<h1>Welcome to my Website!</h1>
```

Will be changed Via PHP to

```
<h2>Hello World!</h1>
```

in PHP:

```
<?Php
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
    // get an edited file
    $page = file_get_contents("page.html"));

    $links = json_decode($_GET['links'], true);

    foreach($links as $link) {
        $page = str_replace($link['tag'], $link['new_tag'], $page);
    }
   file_put_contents("test.html", $page);

    print 'DONE';
```

But sometimes str_replace doesn't replace the tag, eventought by looking at the accepted array, everything is identical to what is stored in page.html.

======================

***EDIT***

example for $_GET['link']

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tag"]=>
    string(28) "<h1>Welcome to Example!</h1>"
    ["tag_modified"]=>
    string(146) "<h1 class="highlighted" onclick="location.href = 'http://www.example.com'">Welcome to Example!.</h1>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tag"]=>
    string(179) "<p>Some Random Text.</p>"
    ["tag_modified"]=>
    string(293) "<p class="highlighted" onclick="location.href = 'http://www.example.com/'">Some Random Text.</p>"
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use `strip_tags()`?

Comment: how is this related? I am sending from jquery HTML code to replace later. I want to replace also the tags, not to strip them. i.e change <h1>hello</h1> to <h2>hello</h2>. by clicking on <h1>hello</h1> i'm sending this tag to php to replace with predefined different tag.

Comment: You should not be sending the whole html tag using ajax. Just send the .text of the element, or the .val of the input tag. Is there a reason you need to send along the html tags too?

Comment: yes ofcourse, because i'm adding HTML attributes into these tags when replacing them. I want to replace  a whole chunk of code, with a different chunk of code. for example, adding to <a> tags an onclick attribute

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828870/php-regex-how-to-get-the-string-value-of-html-tag

Comment: @Satbir - I'm not looking for a tag, i'm looking for text that might contain HTML tags.

Comment: Can you include examples as to what type of input your `$_GET['links']` variable has?

Comment: Can you also provide the JS code you created?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `str_replace` function try using the `preg_replace` functions. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php This link might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the text in the form and assuming you're using jQuery, but not allow any HTML in the text field, then you can do something like this within the page before you submit via ajax:

```
function stripHtml(str) {
  return $('<div></div>').html(str).text();
}
```

Comment: I do not want to change the text, the whole chunk of code

Comment: This won't change the text, just strip HTML

Comment: Again, I want to change a whole chunk of code, including HTML.

Comment: yes, HTML markup that contains text, and other html tags. a user clicks on the client side on an area, I get it with jquery (e.target) and sends it with ajax.

Comment: Without knowing more of what your plugin does, I suggest you simply have the plugin manipulate the HTML in the UI, then pass the entire HTML block that has changed back to the server and simply replace it with the new block. No need to iterate over any code that way.