# PHP find certain character in HTML tag and replace the whole tag by string

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

I have extracted a string value from my sql table and it is like below:

```
<p>Commodity Exchange on 5 April 2016 settled as following graph:</p> 
<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/uploads/986dfdea.png\" 
style=\"height:163px; width:650px\" /></p></p> 
<p>end of string</p>
```

I wish to get image name *986dfdea.png* inside the html tag (because there's a lot of `<p></p>`  tags inside the string, and I want to able to know that this tag contains image), and replace the whole tag content by a symbol, like '#image1'.

Eventually it would become this:

```
<p>Commodity Exchange on 5 April 2016 settled as following graph:</p> 
#image1 
<p>end of string</p>
```

I'm developing API for mobile apps, but having baby skill on PHP, still can't achieve my goal by referring to these references:

[PHP/regex: How to get the string value of HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828870/php-regex-how-to-get-the-string-value-of-html-tag)

[How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

Please help.

Comment: Why do you need `986dfdea.png` if you don't use it after ? you just need to replace  `<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/uploads/986dfdea.png\" 
style=\"height:163px; width:650px\" /></p></p> ` for `#image1` , right ? is there really `</p></p>` or just one ?

Comment: No I don't need it. I have the image name from db, so eventually to replace the #image with the image name inside my mobile apps. I have multiple tags which contains the images. But I will put increment on the symbol string, like #image2. As long as I can achieve the above result, I can kinda sort it out by using for loop .

Comment: So, `#986dfdea.png` would be good ? Which php version are you using ?

Comment: The image name is randomly generated. Suggest to find 'imageuploader', or just '.png', because in my website, the article is done by using open-source word editor. PHP version is 5.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could use a regex and you'd need way less code, but we [shouldn't parse html with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/797495), so here's what you need:

1. Your string contains invalid html (`</p></p>`), so we use
   `tidy_repair_string` to clean it.
2. Use `DOMXpath()` to query for `p` tags with `img` tags inside
3. Remove any extra `"`and get the image filename with `getAttribute("src")` and `basename`
4. Create a new `createTextNode` with the value of image `#imagename`
5. Use `replaceChild` to replace the `p` with image inside with  new `createTextNode` created above.
6. Cleanup the  `!DOCTYPE`, `html` and `body` tags automatically generated by `new DOMDocument();`

---

```
<?php
$html = <<< EOF
<p>Commodity Exchange on 5 April 2016 settled as following graph:</p>
<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/uploads/986dfdea.png\"
style=\"height:163px; width:650px\" /></p></p>
<p>end of string</p>
EOF;



$html = tidy_repair_string($html,array(
                           'output-html'   => true,
                           'wrap'           => 80,
                           'show-body-only' => true,
                           'clean' => true,
                           'input-encoding' => 'utf8',
                           'output-encoding' => 'utf8',
                                          ));


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);



$x = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach($x->query('//p/img') as $pImg){
    //get image name
    $imgFileName = basename(str_replace('"', "", $pImg->getAttribute("src")));
    $replace = $dom->createTextNode("#$imgFileName");
    $pImg->parentNode->replaceChild($replace, $pImg);
    # loadHTML causes a !DOCTYPE tag to be added, so remove it:
    $dom->removeChild($dom->firstChild);
    # it also wraps the code in <html><body></body></html>, so remove that:
    $dom->replaceChild($dom->firstChild->firstChild, $dom->firstChild);
    echo str_replace(array("<body>", "</body>"), "", $dom->saveHTML());

}
```

---

**Output:**

```
<p>Commodity Exchange on 5 April 2016 settled as following graph:</p>
<p>#986dfdea.png</p>
<p>end of string</p>
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/DkgitF)

Comment: It works. This is clean and beautiful. I've learned so much from your codes.. I've saved a lot of my hairs from it too. Thank you so much for your help.