# how to get source link video on film web

Tags: php, get

i have a question.
Example i have a film web, this link: http://www.phimmoi.net/phim/mui-ten-xanh-phan-4-3154/xem-phim.html
I want to get source link video in that link, as to Internet Download Manager software. So how can i get link by php? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In this cases you should get content of link:

for example:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.phimmoi.net/phim/mui-ten-xanh-phan-4-3154/xem-phim.html');
```

Now you have html content of that page and can use from regex for getting video link and even download that with other tools. about regex you can send pattern which this website have and others will suggest regex for you.

See below links about regex:

[How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

[PHP/regex: How to get the string value of HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828870/php-regex-how-to-get-the-string-value-of-html-tag)

see below link about download:

[Download File to server from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url)